# MS Teams - Rich notification are not supported for this resource in 'app + user' context (Graph API)

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-web-app-service, microsoft-teams, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm trying to set up rich notifications for a channel subscription like in the docs below.

> New or changed messages in a specific Teams channel: /teams/{id}/channels/{id}/messages

I'm supplying the details to the subscription url like below with ROPC auth flow.

```
{
    "changeType": "created,updated",
    "notificationUrl": "https://f554-118-110-222-226.ngrok.io/api/teams/events",
    "resource": "teams/TEAM_ID/channels/CHANNEL_ID/messages",
    "expirationDateTime": "2021-10-20T02:55:53Z",
    "encryptionCertificate": "encryptionCertificate",
    "encryptionCertificateId": "encryptionCertificateId",
    "includeResourceData": true,
  }
```

I should have all permissions necessary to access this resource since **I can create a subscription when includeResourceData is false**. However, I'm getting the following **error when includeResourceData is true** and I supply an encryption cert.

> **Operation: Create; Exception: [Status Code: BadRequest; Reason: Rich notification are not supported for this resource in 'app + user' context. Please set includeResourceData field to false.]**

I think it might be with how my auth and permissions are set up but I'm not entirely sure what this means. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Please check this might helpful : https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/3977

Comment: Creating a subscription requires read permission to the resource. For example, to get change notifications on messages, your app needs the Mail.Read permission : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#chatmessage-microsoft-teams

Comment: Please check if the below doc helps you in any way. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks-with-resource-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to my question in this block of the docs. Thanks to RahulKumarShaw-MT for linking the right version.

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#chatmessage

The error below means that since the app was using **ROPC auth flow** it falls under delegated permissions and **is not supported by the API to send encrypted data.**

> Operation: Create; Exception: [Status Code: BadRequest; Reason: Rich
> notification are not supported for this resource in 'app + user'
> context. Please set includeResourceData field to false.]

I got around this by having to set up an additional auth token with app permissions set up specifically for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Would Suggest you to please try to revalidate and setup all the below prerequisite if might you have missed while setup change notification for team’s channel.

- you need to include "includeResourceData" set to "true" and provide certificate information as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#chatmessage-microsoft-teams)
- you need to get your application [approved](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#chatmessage-microsoft-teams)

Other way to subscribe notifications for channel messages dynamically(e.g. powerapp - current user can subscribe to all of his joinedTeams or selected teams and receives push notifications) Because Ms Flows and Logic apps only lets you setup one at a time.

Please follow this [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks-with-resource-data) for Set up change notifications that include resource data while creating subscription.

Reference: [is team channel messages allowed for change notifications beta? · Issue #3977 · microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs · GitHub](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/3977)